# How to combine all children of two peers into one XML node?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have three XML files concatenated into one, such that it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:RBO_Group>
                <wd:Comment_BatchID>kns_timeoff20200105_5365_78659138</wd:Comment_BatchID>
                <wd:Date_Worked>2020-01-02</wd:Date_Worked>
                <wd:Hours>9</wd:Hours>
                <wd:Type>Vacation</wd:Type>
                <wd:Process_Date>2020-02-10</wd:Process_Date>
            </wd:RBO_Group>
            <wd:Employee_ID>106060</wd:Employee_ID>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
    </wd:Report_Data>
    <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:RBO_Group>
                <wd:Date_Worked>2014-12-15</wd:Date_Worked>
                <wd:Hours>41.53</wd:Hours>
                <wd:Type>UNITWAY</wd:Type>
                <wd:Process_Date>2019-09-20</wd:Process_Date>
            </wd:RBO_Group>
            <wd:RBO_Group>
                <wd:Date_Worked>2019-08-04</wd:Date_Worked>
                <wd:Hours>5065.84</wd:Hours>
                <wd:Type>zzzdnu BEREAVEWK2</wd:Type>
                <wd:Process_Date>2019-09-24</wd:Process_Date>
            </wd:RBO_Group>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
    </wd:Report_Data>
    <Data>
        <Worker>
            <INT_ID>228606</INT_ID>
            <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_timeoff20191229_232_78652526</WD_BATCH_ID>
            <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>228602</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
            <DATE_WORKED>2019-12-12</DATE_WORKED>
            <EMPLOYEE_ID>146379</EMPLOYEE_ID>
            <WEEK_END_DATE>2019-12-15</WEEK_END_DATE>
            <EFFECTIVE_DATE>2019-12-29</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
            <HOURS>8</HOURS>
            <PAY_COMPONENT>Jury Duty</PAY_COMPONENT>
            <TK_COMMENTS>kns_wd20191229_232_78652526</TK_COMMENTS>
            <SS_REQUEST_ID>78652508</SS_REQUEST_ID>
            <REQUEST_ID>78652526</REQUEST_ID>
            <PROCESS_DATE>2/6/2020 20:57</PROCESS_DATE>
            <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
        </Worker>
    </Data>
</Root>
```

And I want to combine all the children of the two `<wd:Report_Data>` nodes so that they're all under the same `<wd:Report_Data>` node. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:RBO_Group>
                <wd:Comment_BatchID>kns_timeoff20200105_5365_78659138</wd:Comment_BatchID>
                <wd:Date_Worked>2020-01-02</wd:Date_Worked>
                <wd:Hours>9</wd:Hours>
                <wd:Type>Vacation</wd:Type>
                <wd:Process_Date>2020-02-10</wd:Process_Date>
            </wd:RBO_Group>
            <wd:Employee_ID>106060</wd:Employee_ID>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:RBO_Group>
                <wd:Date_Worked>2014-12-15</wd:Date_Worked>
                <wd:Hours>41.53</wd:Hours>
                <wd:Type>UNITWAY</wd:Type>
                <wd:Process_Date>2019-09-20</wd:Process_Date>
            </wd:RBO_Group>
            <wd:RBO_Group>
                <wd:Date_Worked>2019-08-04</wd:Date_Worked>
                <wd:Hours>5065.84</wd:Hours>
                <wd:Type>zzzdnu BEREAVEWK2</wd:Type>
                <wd:Process_Date>2019-09-24</wd:Process_Date>
            </wd:RBO_Group>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
    </wd:Report_Data>
    <Data>
        <Worker>
            <INT_ID>228606</INT_ID>
            <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_timeoff20191229_232_78652526</WD_BATCH_ID>
            <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>228602</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
            <DATE_WORKED>2019-12-12</DATE_WORKED>
            <EMPLOYEE_ID>146379</EMPLOYEE_ID>
            <WEEK_END_DATE>2019-12-15</WEEK_END_DATE>
            <EFFECTIVE_DATE>2019-12-29</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
            <HOURS>8</HOURS>
            <PAY_COMPONENT>Jury Duty</PAY_COMPONENT>
            <TK_COMMENTS>kns_wd20191229_232_78652526</TK_COMMENTS>
            <SS_REQUEST_ID>78652508</SS_REQUEST_ID>
            <REQUEST_ID>78652526</REQUEST_ID>
            <PROCESS_DATE>2/6/2020 20:57</PROCESS_DATE>
            <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
        </Worker>
    </Data>
</Root>
```

But it's important that the `Data` node remain separate. What's the simplest way for me to copy this XML, and just remove those two lines, so that all the "wd:Report_Entry"s are under the same node?

I've tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
           <xsl:copy-of select="//wd:Report_Entry"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...which ALMOST works. It puts all the Report_Entry nodes under the same parent, but it duplicates the second Report_Entry node, with all its children. It seems like I should be able to qualify the selection with `[1]` but I don't know how I'd do that selection, to apply the template, without the default template picking up the second Report_Data node...

Any suggestions?

Comment: The output you show does not match your description.

Comment: Good catch. I forgot to edit it after I pasted it. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the simplest way would be:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <wd:Report_Data>
             <xsl:copy-of select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry"/>
        </wd:Report_Data>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Data"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is not what you show - but it is what you describe.

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why `select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry"` selects all the `wd:Report_Entry` nodes in both parents. I mean, the answer is "because that's how XPath works," but this is not what I would have expected this to do... Time for more learnin'

Comment: Because to select only `wd:Report_Entry` nodes of one parent you would have to specify which parent - for example: `select="wd:Report_Data[1]/wd:Report_Entry"`.

Answer (score -1):

Please test this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output indent="true"></xsl:output>
    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[not(preceding::wd:Report_Entry)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="//wd:Report_Entry"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This answer needs more description.